# What the "uri" written in nginx doc(difference with the "file")?

Tags: nginx

The last argument of `try_files` directive is slightly different from the others, it has a leading slash(but not means absolute path):
e.g. `try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /fallback/index.html;`.

And [the doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) distinguish them as *`file`* and *`uri`*.

Also [the doc of error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page), the last argument written as *`uri`* and it may internally redirect, like `try_files` one's.

Sum up above, *`uri`* means follows right?:

- start with leading slash(`/`)
- but not serve from absolute path, follow the directory within context
- can cause an internal redirection(= lookup other location directives)

Answer (score 0):

This last URI argument is compared against your `location` blocks - and the best/longest match is used to resolve it. So if you do not have `location /fallback {` in your `nginx.conf` - the above example will return error 404.

Comment: I understood the behavior when try_files or error_page fallbacks to *`uri`*. 
But I wonder that is there any definition or reference for *`uri`*, the doc indicates, to verify my last 3 statements in the question.

Comment: I gonna move to the server fault and close this question